# Version 10 of Mathematica in Windows XP

Tags: version-10, windows, installation, compatibility

I obtained the latest version 10 of Mathematica however, when I start the installation the process aborts and a pop up window explains that "The program requires Windows NT version 6.0 or later". As far as I know, this means that version 10 is compatible only with Vista and all later versions of windows, am I right? In my PC I still have Windows XP SP3. So, is there a way to install version 10 in this OS? Currently, I have version 9 and runs like a charm. I refuse to believe that Wolfram made in purpose version 10 incompatible with XP.

Comment: Why do you think they will support **unsupported** (even extended support) version of OS?

Comment: @m0nhawk Why not? There are still millions of XP users around the world.

Comment: @m0nhawk the installer refuses to install on anything older than Vista (including Server 2003 R2 x64, which is only a few months older than Vista and currently in extended support for another year). I didn't try to override that to see what happens.

Comment: "I refuse to believe that Wolfram made in purpose version 10 incompatible with XP" - perhaps it's not done deliberately? Interesting question though!

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html

Comment: @RolfMertig I see that version 10 is not only for 64-bit OS; it comes in some 32-bit versions. Not including XP in these 32-bit versions is really very disappointed.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I don't work for Wolfram. Maybe somebody from Wolfram Research knows why they stopped support for Windows XP. My uneducated guess is that the cloud functionality (login , etc) is impossible to support.

Comment: Microsoft itself no longer supports Windows XP, so why expect new Wolfram products work with it?

Comment: yet somehow Wolfram supports linux which isn't "supported" by anyone.

Comment: @george2079 linux is supported by several companies: e.g. RedHat, Canonical, SUSE, each with their own version schedule and EOL times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have contacted the Wolfram support (`[CASE:1292216]`):

> Dear Andrew,
>
> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Customer Service. We simply ended our support of XP shortly after Microsoft had announced they would no longer support XP themselves. XP is going to become to difficult to handle without any kind of support from Microsoft as many of the issues we would run into would be from the OS interaction with Mathematica and without updates for the OS each machine could almost be running its own version of XP. Please let us know if we may help further.
>
> Regards, Wolfram Research, Inc.

The only solution: find an installed version and copy, but there is no guarantee it will work (mine worked on Windows XP on Hyper-V VM) and work correctly.

Comment: If I understand correctly your sayings you suggest me to install v10 in Win 8 for example and then copy the entire installation folder from Program Files to my XP PC. Am I right? Another idea the came by to me: Since I have the setup .exe file, can I produce a portable version of it? Few months ago, I found a torrent with a portable v9 that runs in any PC without installation just from a USB stick.

Comment: Yes, or ask someone with installed to share it. But take in account that you will need `x86` version, so you need `x86` version of Win8. About portable... I didn't have any experience with creating portable software, so can't advice anything. I think someone would definitely make it, and it would work seamlessly.

Comment: @m0nhawk I have not tried that yet but what about registry entries that V10 would create?

Comment: @bobbym there is nothing necessary for computations, only some system information, like version or file association (can be added manually).

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable +1

Answer (score 4):

One can use Microsoft Application Verifier to cheat the Windows version.

Comment: [Like so](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wit/archive/2008/11/04/white-lies-using-appverifier-to-test-os-versioning.aspx)? I'm not sure if `HighVersionLie` also works for cheating on lower version numbers; can anyone confirm that this works?

Comment: @Teake Nutma yes, it works.

Comment: Can you then amend your answer with a step-by-step procedure of how to get it working? At the very least, include the command line to wrap the installer in MAV.

Comment: This one does not help

Comment: @Anixx Doesn't work for me. I set major version 6, minor 1, but the installer still is not satisfied.

Comment: @Anixx Yea, shit. Checked the module name. If the installer executable file is ``m.exe``, then the module name when it's started is somehow ``m.tmp``. Works perfectly, upvoting, thanks!

Comment: @Anixx Hmm, well, it has installed, but with some errors at the quite very end, mostly (as I recognize) shortcut link (icons) creation errors and browser plugin DLL registration (though, what is DLL registration?). But the very Mathematica 10 notebook GUI doesn't start with not-a-Win32-app error, while the kernel (both text mode and windowed mode) start up, reports ``Mathematica 10.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)`` and appears to work. So, @Anixx, how have you managed, if it all, to make Mathematica notebook GUI to work on Windows XP (32-bit)?

Comment: @dbanet well he could be using the 64-bit version of Windows XP.

Comment: @shrx that's relatively unluckily... I'd even install 32-bit Server 2003 if I knew Mathematica 10 will start up, but my CPU is non-x86_64-capable, so it would be too bad (and rather strange) if 64-bit Mathematica 10 works both on 7 and XP, but 32-bit Mathematica fails on XP...

Comment: @dbanet maybe Mathematica needs some architecture extensions like SSE to work on your CPU which are absent?

Comment: @Anix I thought of it too, but is there any requirement list? Although SSE would fit the kernel, which starts up perfectly, much more, than the GUI.